# How to isolate a library service from different applications

Tags: android

I have a service in a library project:

```
package com.example.project;
class MyService extends Service;
```

When I add it to an app, I include the service tag in the app manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project.myapp1"...
    <application...
        <service
            android:name="com.example.project.MyService"
            android:exported="false" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MYINTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I send commands to the service using startService, I'm not binding to the service because I need the service to keep running even after the activity is destroyed and not binding was much simpler. And it works fine.

So I create another app using the same library and service:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project.myapp2"...
    <application...
        <service
            android:name="com.example.project.MyService"
            android:exported="false" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MYINTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I can't change the service name, because the service class is the same, right?

The problem is that this second app tries to call the service from the first app instead of its own service.

So how can I isolate services implemented using the same class but running in different apps?

Comment: Can't you just change the intent filter name like `.MYINTENT2` or something ? start second service with this new intent action.

Comment: Yes! That did it! I was pretty sure I tried this before, but probably I was doing something else wrong and thought it didn't work. Don't you want to answer the question so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the intent filter name like `.MYINTENT2` or something, Then, you start second service with this unique new intent action.

Comment: My mistake was to think that I could use the dot abbreviation on the action name and Android would prepend the package name to the action, but it does not, so in the end my actions were using the same name. Thanks!